# How To reuse .getText value in another page Java Selenium

Tags: gettext

I am trying to use .getText and want to use that retrieved text, on another page(Search box).

Can I get any help?

I am using Java Selenium.

Thanks
In advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sessionStorage and store the text using getText() add data
to the session storage and it will be accessible to any page from the same site opened in that window.

**Update**

SessionStorage can store up to approx 5MB of data which will be store on the browser and will be available to the pages which will be open in that tab, It means once you close the tab it will be deleted and not accessible. It expires on the closure of the tab.

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Google offered in:  ']")).getText();
WebStorage s = (WebStorage) new Augmenter().augment(driver);
SessionStorage ss =s.getSessionStorage();
ss.setItem("Text", text);    
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(ss.getItem("Text"),Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: Hi Manish,
I tried but getting the below warning:-

org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter extractRemoteWebDriver
WARNING: Augmenter should be applied to the instances of @Augmentable classes or previously augmented instances only (instance class was: class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver)

Thnaks
Sathesh

Comment: Ok, are you able to store the value ? and use it across other pages of the site

Comment: I can store but when I try to use getting a null value.

Comment: public void copy_FANID() throws Exception {
        String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='fan-id']")).getText();
        System.out.println("My fan" + text);
        s = (WebStorage) new Augmenter().augment(driver);
        ss =s.getSessionStorage();
        ss.setItem("Text", text);
}

The above-extracted fanid need to use on another page to search;

public void paste_FANID() throws Exception {
       
        entervalueinsearchbox.click();
        entervalueinsearchbox.sendKeys(ss.getItem("Text"));

}

Comment: Ok let me check then

Comment: @SatheshDunukunala you need to adjust this if you are using framework, well the given answer is not returning the `null` try to adjust it as per your design of framework you use and for Augmenter warning try to use @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})

Comment: @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})-Redundant suppression Redundant suppression.  Still showing null only.